# Spark classnotfoundexception in UDF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

When I call a function it works. but when I call that function in UDF will not work.

This is full code.

```scala
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HiveFromSpark").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val hive = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

///////////// UDFS
def toDoubleArrayFun(vec:Any) : scala.Array[Double] = {
  return vec.asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[Double]].toArray
}
def toDoubleArray=udf((vec:Any) => toDoubleArrayFun(vec))

//////////// PROCESS
var df = hive.sql("select vec from mst_wordvector_tapi_128dim where word='soccer'")
println("==== test get value then transform")
println(df.head().get(0))
println(toDoubleArrayFun(df.head().get(0)))

println("==== test transform by udf")
df.withColumn("word_v", toDoubleArray(col("vec")))
.show(10);
```

Then this the output.

```
sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@6e9484ad
hive: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = 
toDoubleArrayFun: (vec: Any)Array[Double]
toDoubleArray: org.apache.spark.sql.UserDefinedFunction
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [vec: array<double>]
==== test get value then transform
WrappedArray(-0.88675,, 0.0216657)
[D@4afcc447
==== test transform by udf
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 5, xdad008.band.nhnsystem.com): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$5ba2a895f25683dd48fe725fd825a71$$$$$$iwC$$anonfun$toDoubleArray$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Full output here.
https://gist.github.com/jeesim2/efb52f12d6cd4c1b255fd0c917411370

As you can see "toDoubleArrayFun" function works well, but in udf it claims ClassNotFoundException.

I can not change the hive data structure, and need to convert vec to Array[Double] to make a Vector instance.

So what problem with code above?

Spark version is 1.6.1

**Update 1**

Hive table's 'vec' column type is "`array<double>`"

Below code also cause error

```scala
var df = hive.sql("select vec from mst_wordvector_tapi_128dim where 
word='hh'")
df.printSchema()
var word_vec = df.head().get(0)
println(word_vec)
println(Vectors.dense(word_vec))
```

output

```
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [vec: array<double>]
root
|-- vec: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
==== test get value then transform
word_vec: Any = WrappedArray(-0.88675,...7)
<console>:288: error: overloaded method value dense with alternatives:
(values: Array[Double])org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector <and>
(firstValue: Double,otherValues:Double*)org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
cannot be applied to (Any)
println(Vectors.dense(word_vec))
```

This means hive '`array<double>`' column cant not be casted to `Array<Double>`
Actually I want to calculate distance:Double with two `array<double>` column.
How do I add Vector column based on `array<double>` column?

Typical method is

```
Vectors.sqrt(Vectors.dense(Array<Double>, Array<Double>)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `udf` function has to go serialization and deserialization process, `any` DataType will not work. You will have to define exact DataType of the column you are passing to the `udf` function.

From the output in your question it seems that you have only one column in your dataframe i.e. `vec` which is of `Array[Double]` type

```
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [vec: array<double>]
```

There actually is no need of that udf function as your `vec` column is already of `Array` dataType and that is what your `udf` function is doing as well i.e. casting the value to `Array[Double]`.

Now, your other function call is working

```
println(toDoubleArrayFun(df.head().get(0)))
```

because there is no need of serialization and de-serialization process, its just *scala* function call.

Comment: Ah, serializable was the point! But How do I make dataframe column `Array<Double>`, not Any? I've updated question!

Comment: instead of `Any` in your udf function, just define the datatype as `WrappedArray[Double]` and you should be fine. :)

Comment: Thank you for the kind answers.. btw when I set argument type to `WrappedArray[Double]` instead of `Any` It fails. `<console>:346: error: type mismatch; found   : Any. required: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Double]             println( Vectors.dense(toDoubleArrayFun(df.head().get(0))))`

Comment: i will have to see step by step with what you are doing. and if you update the question again then the question is going to be a mess. so i suggest you to ask another question with step by step process of yours and current problem. I will try to answer that if others don't answer it. and if this answer helped you please accept and upvote. :) thanks